# Technique of code generation in oAW

Tags: oaw

Is there any reference which can explain that how oAW (OpenArchitectureWare) generating php code with Xpand?oAW is using GMF Editor or something else?

Answer (score 0):

[The openArchitectureWare manual](http://www.openarchitectureware.org/pub/documentation/4.3.1/html/contents/emf_tutorial.html) is pretty good at describing how to implement an EMF to PHP through Xpand code generator. There are plenty of real-world example implementation references, for example my project [IAML](http://code.google.com/p/iaml/).

Answer (score 0):

1. There needs to be a model (made out from your input data base) for The oAW (script code you write) to operate on.
2. Once the model is available, the generation can be invoked by a workflow file (.oaw/.mwe) which will invoke the model via the eclipse class (inbuilt)
3. Then in the workflow file, you call an Xpand DEFINE, wherein you have the code written.

I hope this is clear.